# ACCESS VBA Comparing a string against a string in another table

Tags: ms-access, vba

here's my problem.  I have 2 tables
tvehicle and tPMCL
the tVehicle table has a list of our vehicles,  and the tPMCL holds when preventitive maint. is done.

tvhhicle.VehicleTagnumber holds the actual plate number,  and tPMCL.Tag holds only a Index of a look up of that number from when it was entered,  I wish it had the tag number so when i do loops through my data comparing it would be able to match up, as it is:

it's comparing something along the lines of "XPE 269" to 1 and that's not working so well.

Any ideas?  the answer may not be a VBA answer it may be a diferent way to do the lookup in the first place.  But I just can't find another way to do the lookup and actually store the plate number and not an index of it.

Comment: Where is the index coming from? How do you get the plate from the index?

Comment: Is tPMCL.Tag *really an index* or is it a foreign key?

Comment: tMPCL uses this for the lookup whan data is entered:

Comment: SELECT [tVehicle].[ID], tVehicle.[VehicleTagnumber] FROM tVehicle ORDER BY [VehicleTagnumber];

Comment: Seems like you could change the bound column of your combo box to tVehicle.[VehicleTagnumber] and it would then be storing the tag number directly. You could also add the tag number as the primary key (as I don't see why you'd have two vehicles with the same plate) and re-set your referential integrities to correspond with the new key.

Comment: How do i "re-set your referential integrities"

Comment: It's not necessary, but would be good practise to set up proper database relationships between the two tables. For instance, I would have the tVehicle.VehicleTagNumber field as the primary field and tPMCL.VehicleTagNumber as the secondary field in a one-to-many relationship. This ensures that only valid tag numbers can be input into the tPMCL.

Comment: See http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/ms-access-2010-relationship-query-interconnect for more details on relationships and Access2010

Comment: Thanks for the link, I know how to set relationships.  didn't realize you were talking about that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you think of as Index is actually a foreign key. This is a good thing. This means that if VehicalTagNumber where to change (e.g. a bad input) the referring table would not need to be updated.

If you need to loop through the tPMCL and you need the corresponding Tag Number you can do one of two things.

You could use Dlookup to get it on each loop. e.g.

```
Dim strTag As String
strTag = DLookup("[VehicleTagnumber]", "tvhhicle","[Id] = 1")
```

However this will be slow for large numbers of records.

Instead just base your record set on a SQL statement that joins the two table instead of opening a table directly.

```
Dim dbVehicle As Object 
Dim rstVehicle As Object 
Dim fldEnumerator As Object 
Dim fldColumns As Object 
Dim strSQL as String

Set dbVehicle = CurrentDb 
Set rstVehicle = dbVehicle.OpenRecordset("tVehicle") 
Set fldColumns = rstVehicle.Fields 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tMPCL m INNER JOIN tVehicle v ON m.Tag = v.ID" 

Set rsttPMCL = dbVehicle.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: You completely lost me here. my skils with VBA are meeger at best,  and i am unable to follow the logic of what you posted.  I really don't care abvout the sizre if my database.  since we'll have at most 5 or 6 vehicles to at any one time.  over the life of this program my database might reach 10 of 15 MB even with duplicating the data in the 2 tables.

Comment: `Dim dbVehicle As Object Dim rstVehicle As Object Dim fldEnumerator As Object Dim fldColumns As Object Set dbVehicle = CurrentDb Set rstVehicle = dbVehicle.OpenRecordset("tVehicle") Set fldColumns = rstVehicle.Fields Set rsttPMCL = dbVehicle.OpenRecordset("tPMCL")`

Comment: i can't even get my code to display corectly.  and the box isn't large enough to get the small amount of code needed anyway.

Comment: I think i'm almost there with the help @StuckAtWork was giving.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your code in the sample that uses SQL.

Comment: I've got it working now sort of.  another issue but it's a movenext issue ( i think) so i'll start another post for it.  thanks for the help all.  @StuckAtWork your solution is what got my compare code working.

Comment: and i figured out my problem with my move next issue.  again thanks for the help all